# Access to the path xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, wpf-controls

I have problem with, access to the path in canvas, I want to be able to changing the 'fill' in my code(c#).
These is my xaml code:

```
<Canvas Name="hour" Opacity="0.05" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="0" Height="0" >
    <Path Fill="Aquamarine">
        <Path.Data>
            <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50"/>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

How to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give it a name:

```
<Path x:Name="myPath" Fill="Aquamarine">
```

So you can access it in code, like:

```
myPath.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
```